# .NET prerequisites, 3.5sp1 but no 3.5? problem with 4.0?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, runtime

The title is confusing but the problem is not so much.

I made a prerequisite with the default 3.5sp1 and windows installer 3.1.

I ran it in my VM and to my surprise it asked me to install .NET. I checked the version and i have .NET 2 sp1, 3 sp1, 3.5, and two variants  of 4.0 (client and extended beta). I looked in prerequisites and there doesnt seem to be an options for a non 3.5sp1.

Is there some way i can select the non sp1? or compile so i dont need sp1? (it crashes upon startup but i am willing to bet i forgot a resource file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesnt seem to be a way to specify not using a service pack. But the problem is that version of 4.0 (possibly beta) does not come with a 3.5SP thus is incompatible. Looks like your out of luck if your app does indeed work correctly w/o the SP.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps create a new VM and install VS2008 on it *without* the Service Pack.

Comment: The VM already does not have the service pack..... i dont understand how this is a solution. Are you saying try to install visual studios on it without one? I like 2010 tho maybe i should accept the fact that i need to compile with sp and allow the installer to DL 3.5 again (with the sp) to install.

Comment: If you have the 3.5 VM why not just install the 3.5 Service Pack?

What I said was, if you can't do that, create a different VM and use it to recompile the app, but be warned 3.5sp1 is very different to 3.5. (non SP doesn't have entity framework)